# Content Management in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, content-management

Is it possible to link a bluemix website with some kind of content mangement?

I'm trying to build a formular for an event registration website with bluemix.
It must be possible for the promoter of the events to decide which data the participants have to fill out. As an example for a business dinner there is no need to ask if he needs a flight or not and for another event it would be necessary to know it. So the content must be "adaptable" by the promoter because I don't want to write a new website for each event.

Does somebody know a solution for this problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Deploy your site on IBM Containers and utilize the ssh capability to scp your content into the web app/site.

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- create an application with a Cloudant backend. The data stored inside is free form. You then "just" need to define the valid form. I used angular.js and angular-formly (with the form definition stored in Cloudant, so you can edit it)
- Use [PencilBlue](https://pencilblue.org/)  a Node.js CMS using a Mongo backend. Eventually it does all you need
- Use a container with a common engine (e.g. Wordpress)

So you can act depending on how custom you want the solution to be. Let us know what works for you